# Solve or preferable Reduce equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am new to mathematica and trying to solve and reduce the following:

```
Solve[1 - (1 - p^y)^(u (1 - p)) == a, y]
```

or

```
Reduce[1 - (1 - p^y)^(u (1 - p)) == a, y]
```

It does not seem to work, would be very grateful if someone can point out what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general problem is too difficult. Are there any constraints that you can use? For example, if 0 < p < 1 and all values and functions are real

```
Reduce[
  {1 - (1 - p^y)^(u (1 - p)) == a, 0 < p < 1}, y, Reals] // 
 Simplify[#, 0 < p < 1] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was a good remark that I did not think of.